# How to configure the prefered languages of internal Eclipse browser?

Tags: eclipse

I want to change the prefered languages of internal Eclipse browser, but I can't find such settings neither in search in Preferences dialog nor in Google.

Where are they configured? They are not taken from Eclipse, because the language of Eclipse menus in English, and the language the site (Admin Console of WebSphere) is displayed is German (in FF it's displayed in English, so it's the browser settings that matters here).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it uses the system settings, at least for Mars.2 & Windows 8.

I changed the default language in Internet Explorer and restarted Eclipse and it now displays pages in the internal browser according to the selected locale.